# All instances of UserControl display the property value specified for the last one

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls, win-universal-app

I've created a UserControl which is (in its minimized form, for the sake of this question) a TextBlock inside a Grid. Its `Text` property is bound to a `DependencyProperty` called `TitleText` in the code-behind.

On my main XAML page, I place this control 4 times in a `Grid`:

```xml
<usercontrols:ProgramButton TitleText="Top left"     Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="pbTopLeft" />
<usercontrols:ProgramButton TitleText="Bottom left"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="pbBottomLeft" />
<usercontrols:ProgramButton TitleText="Top right"    Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="pbTopRight" />
<usercontrols:ProgramButton TitleText="Bottom right" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="pbBottomRight" />
```

The problem is that during design time, the text in *all of these* controls displays the value for the *last* instance!

Screen capture:

[image: 3/4 UserControls displaying wrong property value]

The relevant XAML of my UserControl looks like this:

```xml
<UserControl
    ...
    x:Name="Root"
    ...
>

<Grid Background="Gray" Padding="25">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" x:Name="TitleTextbox" 
        Foreground="DarkGray" 
        FontSize="40"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        Text="{Binding ElementName=Root, Path=TitleText}" />
</Grid>
```

The relevant code-behind of my UserControl looks like this:

```c#
public string TitleText
{
    get { return TitleTextBox.Text; }
    set { SetValue(TitleTextProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty TitleTextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
   "TitleText", typeof(string), typeof(ProgramButton), new PropertyMetadata(
        new PropertyChangedCallback(TitleTextCallback)));

public static void TitleTextCallback(
    DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    (o as ProgramButton).TitleTextBox.Text = e.NewValue.ToString();
}
```

I can't seem to find out why every control instance displays "Bottom right". The UserControl has "Root" as it's `x:Name` value, which is used as the `ElementName` for binding `Path=TitleText`. This in turn is declared as a `DependencyProperty` which is registered as "TitleText". Each one has a unique `x:Name` identifier, so I wouldn't know why this doesn't work as expected.

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

For starters, TitleTextCallback is unnecessary since binding to TitleText is already set. Getter of TitleText should look as follows:

```
get { return (string)GetValue(TitleTextProperty); }
```

Comment: I've removed the `TitleTextCallback` part and replaced the getter of `TitleText` with your line of code, but that did not solve the problem.

Comment: Yes, only the design view displays "_Bottom right_" for every UserControl.